# Cocoa Merging Custom Views

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, view

Currently, I have an NSStatusItem that, when clicked, shows a custom view below it. The view contains some information and text fields. What I need is for a separate custom view to merge with the first and appear below it, as in further down the screen, not on top or behind the original view. This needs to be a separate view because there are actually several custom view that will be appended depending on what the user does in the first view. I would like to be able to independently add or remove each of these without affecting the others. I've dug through apple documentation but I haven't found anything about putting one custom view inside another programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) has an `addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:` method you can use to add and order views to appear above or below each other. Use `superview:` to access this method on a container from any of its subviews.

**Edit:**

Try adding both views to an NSSplitView with a hidden divider. To hide the divider, subclass NSSplitView and override the `dividerThickness:` method to return 0;

Comment: This almost works, but "positioned" has only NSWindowAbove or Below, which places the view on top, or behind my view, not literally below it. I want one view below the other.

Comment: Oh, so it's the y-position, not the z-position you want to change?